# InAppBrowserでのページ遷移時のloading表示について

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, webview

初心者の質問ですみせん。
monacaにてInAppBrowserを使ってwebサイトへ飛ばした際に、webサイトが表示されるまでの間にloading画面を付けたいのですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

分かる方是非、お助け下さいm(__)m

Answer (score 1):

`ons-modal`で`Loading...`と表示し、`InAppBrowser`を`hidden`状態でWebサイトにアクセスします。
読み込みが完了すると`loadstop`イベントが発火するので、`ons-modal`を閉じて`InAppBrowser`を表示します。
ただし、外部ブラウザ(`_system`)を指定した場合は機能しません。

[ons-modal](https://ja.onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-modal.html)
[InAppBrowser プラグイン](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/inappbrowser/)

**HTML**

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Test</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <br>
    <ons-button onclick="showWeb()">Webサイト表示</ons-button>
</ons-page>
<ons-modal>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <p><ons-icon icon="md-spinner" size="28px" spin></ons-icon>&nbsp; Loading...</p>
    </div>
</ons-modal>
```

**JavaScript**

```
"use strict";
ons.ready(function() {
    console.log("Onsen UI is ready!");
});
function showWeb() {
    var modal = document.querySelector("ons-modal");
    modal.show();
    var ref = window.open("http://ja.stackoverflow.com/", "_blank", "location=no,hidden=yes");
    ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(e) {
        modal.hide();
        ref.show();
    });
}
```